# Symfony2 HttpKernel Before and after methods in controllers (Kohana Style)

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, listener, symfony-2.1

I know that this problem was discussed so many times but I had found some solution and I'm not sure if it is the best and the most efficient approach.

My problem: I'm using fosuserbundle to handle user authentication and I would also like to prevent displaying of login, password resetting, etc. form for logged in users. Below I put some approaches:

1. The first one (which has been already implemented) based on the kernel events, there is a code
   https://gist.github.com/walmen/871c13014b80c6a3d05d
2. The second approach which was mentioned by my colleague based on the method overloading (removing listeners and duplicate code in the each method which has some logic which shouldn't be displayed for logged in users)
3. Write custom annotation, i.e. @RequireAnonymous

As I mentioned before, I've already implemented the first approach but I'm not sure if it is the best and the most efficient solution (this listener would be called for each request - it is not too heavy load for application? How listeners affect the application, if they?).

The second approach is the easiest one of course but...code duplication doesn't sound really nice.

The last one might be the best but If we take a look on this example https://gist.github.com/cystbear/1391850 we will see that there is also problem with calling event during any controller call.

Any advice or other ideas with good arguments and explanation?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can use the third approach with the [JMSSecurityExtraBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSecurityExtraBundle) which is included with Symfony Standard.

On the action's you want to exclude from authenticated users you can do like so:

```
/**
 * @Secure(roles="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY")
 */
public function fooAction()
{
    // stuff...
}
```

This ensures that the user requesting the specific path is not authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

@Ramon not really because every user has the role IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, even the authenticated ones.

What is more we don't want to throw an exception like "Access denied" or something but we want to 'hide' those pages thanks to the redirection.

What do you think about this https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/996#issuecomment-14812806 ?